# Influence of DTOs number to GWT application performance

Tags: gwt, dto

Can the number of DTOs affect the performance of GWT applications?

My question comes from following issue. Lets assume that I have to transfer 3 different objects but all with only one String field. Should I create and use 3 different DTOs with meaningful names or one generic (sth like StringDTO).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you plan to transfer thousands of these objects per second, the difference in performance would be negligible, if any.

I always prefer to go with the code that is easier to read, maintain and extend, unless there is a very significant performance issue that may require a different approach.